# How to read text values from an adobe air application screen

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

Hi
I have two air applications say App-A and App-B. I will run both these applications on the same computer and connect both these applications using local connection.

I want to extract all the text values

Comment: What do you mean by "extract all the text values"?

Comment: +! to @florian F .  You're going to have expand on what you want to do.

Comment: So, are you looking to traverse the visual tree and extract the text elements?  "I want to extract all the text values" is a very vague requirement, IMO.

Comment: Hi, I have missed some text. Lets say the screen has one viewstact with 4 views and each view has multiple containers (say there are four containers in a view two containers will be made visible depending on user action). Now I want to extract all the text values from the screen. say second child is selected in the viewstack and in the second child say first and third containers are made visible. Now I want to extract the text that is visible in the screen. I mean the text values available in second child of viewstack (only first and third containers)